# Why isn't my data merge command working?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make a repeating command block that makes an arrow have an entity riding it when shot (I'm using a pig here as an example) but for some reason it says it modified the data, but it isn't working. Can anyone help please?

My command:

```
data merge entity @e[limit=1,type=minecraft:arrow] {Passengers:[{id:pig}]}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you cannot modify/merge an entity's `Passengers` tag after being spawned. You can only modify this tag when the entity is being spawned.